# LiveData with multiple sources of different types

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I currently have a project that contains a list of `MyItem`, and using Firebase/LiveData. It's structured into groups, and each group has items.

I want to be able to update this list if any of the following happen:

1. An item is updated (on the backend through Firebase)
2. A filter is changed (a separate table on Firebase for each user)
3. An item is bookmarked (a separate table on Firebase for each user)

To get the list of contents, I have a function like this to return LiveData that will update whenever an item is updated (#1).

### database

```
getList(id: String): LiveData<List<MyItem>> {
    val data = MutableLiveData<List<MyItem>>()

    firestore
        .collection("groups")
        .document(id)
        .collection("items")
            .addSnapshotListener { snapshot, exception ->
                val items = snapshot?.toObjects(MyItem::class.java) ?: emptyList()

                // filter items 

                data.postValue(items)
        }

    return data
}
```

And within my ViewModel, I have logic for handling that case.

### viewmodel

```
private val result = MediatorLiveData<Resource<List<MyItem>>>()

private var source: LiveData<List<MyItem>>? = null
val contents: LiveData<Resource<List<MyItem>>>
    get() {
        val group = database.group

        // if the selected group is changed.
        return Transformations.switchMap(group) { id ->
            // showing loading indicator
            result.value = Resource.loading(null)

            if (id != null) {
                // only 1 source for the current group
                source?.let {
                    result.removeSource(it)
                }

                source = database.getList(id).also {
                    result.addSource(it) {
                        result.value = Resource.success(it)
                    }
                }

                // how to add in source of filter changes?

            } else {
                result.value = Resource.init(null)
            }
            return@switchMap result
        }
    }
```

The logic is pretty complex, and hard to follow. Is there a better way to structure this to handle multiple different changes? What's the best way to store the user's current filters?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know am I get your question correctly or not, but if you have a view that work with one list (something like `MyItemList`) and this list updated or changed by several situations, you must work with `MediatorLiveData`.

I mean you must have three `LiveData` that each one responsible for a situation and one MediatorLiveData that notified if each one of them has changed.

see below:

### **database**

```
fun getListFromServer(id: String): LiveData<List<MyItem>> {
    val dataFromServer = MutableLiveData<List<MyItem>>()

    firestore
      .collection("groups")
      .document(id)
      .collection("items")
          .addSnapshotListener { snapshot, exception ->
              val items = snapshot?.toObjects(MyItem::class.java) ?: emptyList()
              dataFromServer.postValue(items)
      }

    return dataFromServer
}

fun getFilteredData(id: String): LiveData<FilterData> {
    return DAO.user.getFilteredData(id)
}

fun getBookmarkedList(id: String): LiveData<BookmarkData> {
    return DAO.user.getBookmarkedData(id)
}
```

And in the `viewModel` you have one `MediatorLiveData` that observe on these `liveData`s till if any data has changed notify view.

### **viewModel**

```
private val result = MediatorLiveData<<List<MyItem>>()

fun observeOnData(id: String, owner: LifeCycleOwner, observer: Observer<List<MyItem>>) {
   result.observe(owner, observer);

   result.addSource(Database.getListFromServer(id), MyItemList -> {
        if(MyItemList != null)
            result.setValue(MyItemList)
   });
   result.addSource(Database.getFilteredData(id), filterData -> {
        if(filterData != null) {
            val myItemList = result.getValue()
            if (myItemList == null) return

            //here add logic for update myItemList depend On filterData

            result.setValue(myItemList)
        }
   });
   result.addSource(Database.getBookmarkedList(id), bookmarkData -> {
        if(MyItemList != null) {
            val myItemList = result.getValue()
            if (myItemList == null) return

            //here add logic for update myItemList depend On bookmarkData

            result.setValue(myItemList)
        }
   });

}
```

Comment: The `getFilteredData()` and `getBookmarkedList()` do not return a list of `MyItem`, they return different Objects, such as a `Filter` to search by, so I can't simply set the value of the `result` in the `ViewModel`. I think I need to either cache the entire list from `getListFromServer()`, or I need to make that call again after getting the new `Filter`.

Comment: @Advice-Dog in `addSource` section you can add any logic that customizes your list. see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of `contents` includes several references to outer variables, which makes it hard to follow and keep track of the state. I'd just keep the references as local as possible and trust `switchMap(liveData)` to do a proper job. The following code should be doing just the same as yours:

```
val contents = Transformations.switchMap(database.group) { id ->
    val data = MediatorLiveData<Resource<List<MyItem>>()

    if (id == null) {
        data.value = Resource.init(null)
    } else {
        data.value = Resource.loading(null)
        data.addSource(database.getList(id)) {
            data.value = Resource.success(it)
        }
    }

    return liveData
}
```

In regards of `getList(id)` you might also want to handle the `exception` properly.